# How to make a customized user registration form using the built in wp-register() template tag

Tags: custom-field, wp-register-script

I want to make a registration form in WordPress, but i need it to contain my own custom input fields.

For instance, i need it to have an input field such as COUNTRY, SCHOOL, COURSE, YEAR_OF_ADMISSION, AGE etc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Codex has an article that outlines how to do this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

It even provides an example:

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );

function myplugin_register_form() {
    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );

function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );

function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, just what i needed, but i saw in the codex that if one will make use of custom user meta, that one may need to create additional admin UI. if u can/have access to a link on how to create such additional admin UI pls do point me to such, in order for me to have a comprehensive understanding of it. Thanks

Comment: The profile screen has a few action hooks you tap into to add your fields:

`do_action( 'show_user_profile', $profileuser );` and `do_action( 'edit_user_profile', $profileuser );`

There's a nice write up here: http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-custom-user-profile-fields